# How add the EditedFormattedValues in all the cells in single column after leaving the datagridview in c#.net

Tags: datagridview, cell

I want to add(sum) the all the values from single column and display into one textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Leave` event of the `DataGridView` for this.

```
private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
    }
    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```